# Solve non-linear Optimization Problem

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

I have to find $x$ that minimizes: $$ \sum_{k}(x^H\textbf A_kx - b_k)^2$$ where $A_k$ are 4 x 4 positive definite matrices ($A_1, A_2,...A_k$), $x$ is 4 x 1 vector and $b_k$ are scalars ($b_1,b_2,...b_k)$. Can anyone give me some suggestion/hint inorder to solve this OP ?

Comment: You will probably have to use a numerical approach like [Gauss-Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm) or [BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Since this nonlinear OP will have multiple local minima (multiple $x$ that would solve the OP), is it possible to solve in a way that $x$ is a global minimum?

Comment: Since you did not mention any constraints: can one safely assume there are no constraints for $x$?

Comment: Yes, there are no constraints for $x$ in general (the only condition is that $Rank(x^Hx)=1$, which is automatically satisfied based on definition of the OP so I haven't consider that as a constraint). I am looking for an approach that would yield an $x$ which is a global minimum. Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.